# Using Update statement with the _PARTITIONDATE Pseudo-column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to update a table in BigQuery that is partitioned on _PARTITIONTIME and really struggling.

Source is an extract from destination that I need to backfill destination with. Destination is a large partitioned table.

To move data from source to destination, I tried this:

```
update t1 AS destination
set destination._PARTITIONTIME = '2022-02-09'
from t2 as source
WHERE source.id <> "1";
```

Because it said that the WHERE clause was required for UPDATE, but when I run it, I get a message that "update/merge must match at most one source row for each target row". I've tried... so many other methods that I can't even remember them all. INSERT INTO seemed like a no-brainer early on but it wants me to specify column names and these tables have about 800 columns each so that's less than ideal.

I would have expected this most recent attempt to work because if I do

```
select * from source where source.id <> "1";
```

I do, in fact, get results exactly the way I would expect, so that query clearly functions, but for some reason it can't load the data. This is interesting, because I created the source table by running something along the lines of:

```
select * from destination where DATE(createddate) = '2022-02-09' and DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = '2022-02-10'
```

Is there a way to make Insert Into work for me in this instance? If there is not, does someone have an alternate approach they recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `bq` command line tool (usually comes with the `gcloud` command line utility) to run a query that will overwrite a partition in a target table with your query results:

```sh
bq query --allow_large_results --replace --noflatten_results --destination_table 'target_db.target_table$20220209' "select field1, field2, field3 from source_db.source_table where _PARTITIONTIME = '2022-02-09'";
```

- Note the `$YYYYMMMDD` postfix with the `target_table`. This indicates
  that the partition corresponding to `YYYYMMDD` is to be overwritten
  by the query results.
- Make sure to *distinctively* select fields in your query (as a good practice) to avoid unexpected surprises. For instance, `select field1, field2, field3 from table` is way more explicit and readable than `select * from table`.

Comment: My reply didn't go where I intended, thanks mobile. So this table (and others like it) have about 800 columns so I'll have to script something, I think. hypothetically, would the select * work just for the purposes of getting something done?

Comment: I think so. It should work. Although, this many columns in a single table is a questionable approach on its own.

Comment: It makes more sense in context.